# Docker volume file binding through gitlab executor fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm having a problem mounting a file through volume using docker-compose. When mounting on local machine there's no errors occuring, but when mounting is happening on gitlab executor the file mount is failing. If the path is replaced as folder the error dissapears.

> NOTE: The ${FILES_DIRECTORY} is absolute path.

This works (using folders instead files):

```
volumes:
  - type: volume
    source: ${FILES_DIRECTORY}/uploads
    target: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads
  - type: volume
    source: ${FILES_DIRECTORY}/test
    target: /var/www/html/test
```

This fails (using files directly):

```
volumes:
  - type: volume
    source: ${FILES_DIRECTORY}/uploads.ini
    target: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
  - type: volume
    source: ${FILES_DIRECTORY}/wp-config.php
    target: /var/www/html/wp-config.php
```

Fail log:

> ERROR: for wordpress_sandra  Cannot start service wordpress: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\"/var/www/html/sandra/wp-config.php\\" to rootfs \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6cbe5f406a887cabfc1b42303f2469fe61de263e9a769192a82bfbe5753e5d5f/merged\\" at \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6cbe5f406a887cabfc1b42303f2469fe61de263e9a769192a82bfbe5753e5d5f/merged/var/www/html/wp-config.php\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
>
> ERROR: for wordpress  Cannot start service wordpress: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\"/var/www/html/sandra/wp-config.php\\" to rootfs \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6cbe5f406a887cabfc1b42303f2469fe61de263e9a769192a82bfbe5753e5d5f/merged\\" at \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6cbe5f406a887cabfc1b42303f2469fe61de263e9a769192a82bfbe5753e5d5f/merged/var/www/html/wp-config.php\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type